# Reverse Engineering Ef Code First with Fluent Mappings

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6

The old Entity Framework Power Tools extension used to generate the Code First Domain classes and mapping classes (which used the Fluent API for constraints etc).

I favour the use of mapping classes over data annotations as you have cleaner models.

The Visual Studio wizard which reverse engineers a domain from a database uses a combination of Data Annotations and fluent code in the Model event handler.

This is nowhere near as clean.

Does anyone know if there is a tool which reverse engineers a database in the same way as the Entity Framework Power Tools?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the "Ef Reverse POCO template" favors fluent configuration: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=SimonHughes.EntityFrameworkReversePOCOGenerator

Comment: Thanks Erik. I'll mark this as the answer, but I don't like tt files. It brings a maintenance overhead which I can't abide. But I appreciate the answer, which is correct and will probably help others :)

Comment: All these solutions are based on tt files, actually